# Mix force.com and Site.co Pages within Site

Tags: force.com, site.com

I've a site built using VF and Apex, but I'd like to add visibility of Cases and Chatter without having to re-write a custom skin for the Cases and Chatter elements.

Can I mix some site.com pages within my Force.com site, for example, clicking on "My Tickets" will open a Site.com page (styled same as my Force.com pages)?

Would the login by the user (Communities) still persist across clicking that link?

Paddy

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE user1517428. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). I'd expect you'd have unique domains/subdomains for your force.com site and site.com site. Do you have a unique URL as a log-in within your Force.com site for Communities? Cases can be added to Communities. More details on how you have them set up with your log-in controllers, type of community, etc, and security would be helpful to anyone who might try to answer your question.